# Cannot add propery to object in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to write a function to response http request.
This is my code:

```
const listTask = async (req, res) => {
    let tasks = await Task.find();
    let works = await Work.find().select({_id: 1, name: 1});
    tasks.forEach(t => {
      work = works.find(c => parseInt(c._id) === parseInt(t.work_id));
      t.work = work;
      console.log(t);
    });
    res.status(200).json(tasks);
}
```

In this function, `Task` and `Work` are models created by `mongoose`. A loop by `forEach` to search each elements in array `tasks`. Here, i want to create new property to store `work` object. But message in console doesn't have `work` property.

I tried to use `console.log(t.work)`, the message is same with work.
I also wrote a similar function:

```
function get_full_name_display(users){
    users.forEach(u => {
        u.full_name_display = u.full_name;
    })
    return users;
};
```

and this function worked perfectly. So anyone can explain why and suggest a solution?

Thanks so much. 
Sorry for bad English, i've used Translate Tools a lots.

Comment: are you sure `works.find(c => parseInt(c._id) === parseInt(t.work_id))` isn't returning `undefined`?

Comment: also, not very familiar with Mongoose, but is it maybe set up to be immutable (i.e. modifying property may not work) see: http://thecodebarbarian.com/whats-new-in-mongoose-5-6-immutable-properties.html

Comment: Are you able to see the value of `work` using `console.log(work)`?

Comment: @Zach Lysobey find() function return a object as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing as mentioned above also is your 'work' variable is not declared properly.
Another point is that any result returned from mongoose model is immutable(i.e mongoose objects and not plain js objects), so you cannot directly change properties in 'tasks'.
try the below code:

```
const listTask = async (req, res) => {
    let tasks = await Task.find().lean();
    let works = await Work.find().select({_id: 1, name: 1}).lean();
    tasks.forEach(t => {
      const work = works.find(c => parseInt(c._id) === parseInt(t.work_id));
      t.work = work;
      console.log(t);
    });
    res.status(200).json(tasks);
}
```

you can read more about lean on here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html

Answer (score 1):

Your "work" variable is globally scoped now, you should add **let** in front of it, to keep the scope inside the function.

```
let work = works.find(c => parseInt(c._id) === parseInt(t.work_id));
```

Comment: Wouldn't work be found even if it's global? the execution context will eventually end up in the global context and will find that variable, I don't think this solves the problem but it's helpful as a comment

Comment: It would be found, but only if the "work" variable is not null in the last task in the task list. I think this will solve it.

Comment: @ mAhMoUdDaFeR Fixed it, but it doesn't solve my problem.
@Igor type of returned result is object

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure why you can't set that property but it's possible that you'd have more success using an immutable pattern:

```
const listTask = async (req, res) => {
  const tasks = await Task.find();
  const works = await Work.find().select({_id: 1, name: 1});
  res.status(200).json(tasks.map(task => ({
    ...task,
    work: works.find(c => parseInt(c._id) === parseInt(t.work_id))
  })));
}
```